# How to plot successive times of the day using subplots in python

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I'm graphing data with python, and want to see how amplitude change during a day. I have a fits file that contains the data I want to plot and looks like this:

```
[ 0  1  2 ... 86397  86398  86399]
```

This one is the time in seconds.

```
[ -28.3  -27.84 -29.88 ... 0.18  -0.92  -0.28]
```

This one is the amplitude in dB

I wrote a python code where the time changes from seconds to the format '%H:%M:%S' and data from which the amplitude is, like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import matplotlib
from datetime import datetime

#Dimensiones de la figura a graficar
fig_size = [18, 20]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

data_vlf = fits.open('PLO-20171018.fits')
t = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[0]
time_vlf = t.astype(int)
time_format = [str(timedelta(seconds=s)) for s in time_vlf]
t_format = '%H:%M:%S'
date_vlf = [datetime.strptime(i, t_format).time() for i in time_format]
ch = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[6]

pylab.plot(date_vlf, ch, color='black')
plt.legend(['Channel 6'])
plt.xlabel('Time UT')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

But I also want to see how the amplitude changes for each hour of the day, so I wrote this code but it is not working as I wish.

```py
h_i = 0
h_i_2 = 3600
h_f = 21600

for i in range(1, 7):
    for num1 in range(h_i, h_f, 3600):
        for num2 in range(h_i_2, h_f+1, 3600):
            t_1 = date_vlf[num1:num2]
            ch_1 = ch[num1:num2]
    plt.subplot(3, 2, i)
    pylab.plot(t_1, ch_1)
    plt.xlabel('1 hour (UT)')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

But I am doing wrong.
I am new at python. 
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Basically create 6 axes that will each correspond to the subplots. What I assume is going wrong is that you are only showing one plot at the end of the loop

```py
h_i = 0
h_i_2 = 3600
h_f = 21600

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2) # I added this
for i, ax in zip(range(1, 7), axes.ravel()):
    for num1 in range(h_i, h_f, 3600):
        for num2 in range(h_i_2, h_f+1, 3600):
            t_1 = date_vlf[num1:num2]
            ch_1 = ch[num1:num2]
    ax.plot(t_1, ch_1) # removed a line and changed to this
    ax.set_xlabel('1 hour (UT)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```